# Displaying internal intent within a fragmentnot working

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-studio, android-intent

I have a code to call the intent to display the running services screen. But i wanted it to be displayed within a fragment. But am not able to do that. I call this intent from the java class "bottompage.java" which is the fragment for bottom half of the page. But still when the button is clicked this intent occupies the full screen.

Activity main:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.app_display);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer1, new TopPage());
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer2, new BottomPage());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

}
```

Bottompage.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View secondview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_fragment,container,false);
    Button dummy = (Button) secondview.findViewById(R.id.dummy);

    dummy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            final String APP_DETAILS_PACKAGE_NAME ="com.android.settings";
            // Here you need to define the  package name

            final String SCREEN_CLASS_NAME ="com.android.settings.RunningServices";
            Intent servicesintent = new Intent();
            servicesintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            servicesintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            servicesintent.setClassName(APP_DETAILS_PACKAGE_NAME, SCREEN_CLASS_NAME);

            BottomPage.this.getActivity().startActivity(servicesintent);
        }
    });
    return secondview;
}
```

Main.xml
The xml file for 2 fragments

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="157dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Second page"
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.06" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id ="@+id/fragmentContainer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.06"></FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id ="@+id/fragmentContainer2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragmentContainer1"></FrameLayout>
```

The xml file for the bottom fragment
BottomPage.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/bottom_fragment">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="call services"
    android:id="@+id/dummy"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

How do i make the intent "servicesintent" in bottompage.java to display the running services within the fragment "fragmentcontainer2". Currently its taking full screen.

Comment: intent is a new activity and can't be shown as part of current screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not shure what you exactly want

I use this code to display the Intent that activated my Fragment in the Log.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Activity parent = this.getActivity();
    Intent intent = (parent == null) ? null : parent.getIntent();

    if (intent != null) {
        Log.d(Global.LOG_CONTEXT, "onCreateView " +
             intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME));
    }
```

Instead of adding it to the Log you can set the value to a textview.

Comment: HI... i wanted the screen that comes by calling the intent servicesintent.setClassName(APP_DETAILS_PACKAGE_NAME, SCREEN_CLASS_NAME);
 BottomPage.this.getActivity().startActivity(servicesintent); to be displayed within the area of "fragment container2 " of the mainxml

Comment: Log.d(Global.LOG_CONTEXT, "dummy.OnClickListener " +
             servicesintent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME));

Answer (score 0):

> How do i make the intent "servicesintent" in bottompage.java to display the running services within the fragment "fragmentcontainer2".

You don't. You cannot embed third-party UIs inside your own, except in very specific circumstances (e.g., app widgets and a home screen).

Also note that there is no requirement that any device have a `com.android.settings.RunningServices` activity in `com.android.settings` that is exported.